# Permutate items on shelf positions using C#

Tags: c#, linq, permutation, combinations

I'm trying to solve a permutation problem but I'm having a few issues.

I have a "shelf" that can fit various types of items. Shelf is divided in positions and items have a "size class" which indicate how much room it takes on the shelf itself.

I want to generate for a shelf of 4 positions max `(1,2,3,4)` all the filling combinations with 3 items `(A,B,C)` with a size class that takes 1 position. `(eg. AAAA, AAAB, AAAC, BBBB, BBBA, ...)`.

Next step, I'll need to generate permutations with an item that takes 2 positions. So I need to generate 2 position with `(A,B,C)` and 1 position with `(D,E,F)` `(eg. AAD, AAE, ABD, ...)`

I've tried to use this library [here](http://www.codeproject.com/articles/26050/permutations-combinations-and-variations-using-c-g) but my solution is far from being nice (and it doesn't solve the second example)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Facet.Combinatorics;

namespace iCombine
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            char[] inputSet = "ABCABCABCABC".ToCharArray ();
            IList<string> uniques = new List<string>(); 

            var combinations = new Combinations<char> (inputSet, 4, GenerateOption.WithoutRepetition);
            foreach (var combination in combinations) {
                var permutations = new Permutations<char> (combination, GenerateOption.WithoutRepetition);
                foreach (IList<char> permutation in permutations) {     
                    string token = new string (permutation.ToArray(), 0, 4);
                    if (!uniques.Contains(token))
                        uniques.Add(token);
                }
            }                   
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestion is welcome :)

Comment: Are you limited to only 4 positions?  If so, then this can easily be implemented with 4 nested loops.

Comment: it's not homework :), it's a project I need to complete for my firm. There are various sets I need to generate and insert them into a database. Performance is not really an issue, I'm just trying to understand if the approach is statistically correct. Seems that papers around the web doesn't consider solutions for problems with "token" repetition... If you see my code I've tricked the library by using an input string that repeat each character 4 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will generate all 81 permutations for your first example:

```
var items = new List<char>{'A', 'B', 'C'};

var perms = from a in items
            from b in items
            from c in items
            from d in items
            select new string(new char[]{a, b, c, d});
```

e.g.

```
AAAA 
AAAB 
AAAC 
AABA 
AABB 
...
```

and this the 27 permutations for your second example:

```
var items = new List<char>{'A', 'B', 'C'};
var items2 = new List<char> {'D', 'E', 'F'};

var perms = from a in items
            from b in items
            from c in items2
            select new string(new char[]{a, b, c});
```

The equivalent method syntax uses [Enumerable.SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) which projects each element of a sequence to an `IEnumerable<T>` and flattens the resulting sequences into one sequence.

So the above query could be written as:

```
var items = new List<char> { 'A', 'B', 'C' };
var items2 = new List<char> { 'D', 'E', 'F' };

var perms = items.SelectMany(a => items, (a, b) => new { a, b })
            .SelectMany(t => items2, (t, c) => new string(new[] { t.a, t.b, c }));
```

Comment: Plain and easy! Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is pretty great.  I didn't realize that the Linq Query syntax supported this type of thing.  Do you happen to know offhand what the method syntax would look like?

Comment: @PeteBaughman - updated answer, but comprehension syntax is easier in this case.